# In clojure, how to apply a macro to a list?

Tags: clojure

In `clojure`, `apply` cannot be applied to a macro. For instance `(apply and [true false])` raises an exception. I was thinking about following workaround:

```
(defmacro apply-macro[func args] `(~func ~@args))
```

At first glance, it seemed to work pretty well:

```
(apply-macro and [true 5]); 5
(apply-macro and [true 5 0]); 0
(let [a 0] (apply-macro and [true a])); 0
```

But, when I passed to it a variable that points to a vector, it collapsed.

```
(let [a [true]] (apply-macro and a));  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
   ;Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol
```

What a disappointment!!!!

Any idea how to fix `apply-macro`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The problem is that `a` is just a symbol at compile time. So there's no way for a compile-time macro to see what it contains and do the necessary expansion. As a result, you need to expand the macro at run-time using [eval](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/eval).

One way to do this is just to wrap the macro in a function that calls eval, which can be done with this handy "functionize" macro:

```
(defmacro functionize [macro]
  `(fn [& args#] (eval (cons '~macro args#))))

(let [a [true]] (apply (functionize and) a))
=> true
```

If you like, you could also define apply-macro in terms of functionize:

```
(defmacro apply-macro [macro args]
   `(apply (functionize ~macro) ~args))

(let [a [true false]] (apply-macro and a))
=> false
```

Having said all this, I still think the best thing to do is to avoid macros entirely when they are not really needed: they add extra complexity and are best reserved for cases when you really need compile time code generation. In this case you don't: [Alex Taggart's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9273560/214010) gives a good example of how to achieve a similar objective without any macros, which is probably more appropriate in most situations.

Comment: @YehonathanSharvit: the point is that `(apply-macro and a)` gets expanded to `(and <splice a into the form>)` at **read** time, but `a` gets only defined at **evaluation** time. So the `unquote-splicing` of `a` (i.e. `~@a`) fails, because `a` has not yet been defined.

Comment: Sure, `a` is a vector at run-time. But that's no use if you want to construct an `(and ....)` form at with the contents of `a` at compile time, since the compiler can't see the contents of `a`. Hence you need to call the compiler *again* at runtime once you know what `a` contains, hence the need for eval. It's a bit convoluted but hope that logic makes sense.....

Comment: I just invented functionize in response to your question. I think it's fairly general purpose but haven't exactly tested it in the field :-)

Comment: As a community we should try to avoid encouraging the inexperienced to over-use macros in general and `eval` in particular, especially when there are better tools for the job.

Comment: Alex - totally agree, I've added a suitable caveat :-)

Answer (score 34):

You don't.

Macros are expanded during evaluation/compile time, not at runtime, thus the only information they can use are the args passed in, *but not what the args evaluate to at runtime*.  That's why a literal vector works, because that literal vector is there at compile time, but `a` is just a symbol; it will only evaluate to a vector at runtime.

To have `and`-like behaviour for lists, use `(every? identity coll)`.

To have `or`-like behaviour for lists, use `(some identity coll)`.

Answer (score 2):

When applying args to a conditional macros such as `or`, `case`, `cond` & `condp` for example. You can use the `some`, `every` & `partition` functions. The single else clause is left out in these examples but can  be added rather easily

```
;apply to the 'or' macro
(some identity [nil false 1 2 3])
=> 1

;apply to the 'case' macro.
(some
  (fn [[case value]]
    (and (= case 2) value))
  (partition 2 [1 "one" 2 "two" 3 "three"]))
=> "two"

;apply to the 'cond' macro
(some
  (fn [[case value]]
    (and case value))
  (partition 2 [false "one" true "two" false "three" :else "four"]))
=> "two"

;apply to the 'condp' macro
(let [[f v & args] [= 2 1 "one" 2 "two" 3 "three"]]
  (some
    (fn [[case value]]
      (and (f case v) value))
    (partition 2 args)))
```

`every?` can be used for the `and` macro

```
;apply to the 'and' macro
(every? identity [true true true])
=> true
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course, the proper answer is **don't do this**. But, since I can't resist a good hack:

```
(defmacro apply-macro
  "Applies macro to the argument list formed by prepending intervening
  arguments to args."
  {:arglists '([macro args]
               [macro x args]
               [macro x y args]
               [macro x y z args]
               [macro a b c d & args])}
  [macro & args+rest]
  (let [args (butlast args+rest)
        rest-args (eval (last args+rest))]
    `(eval
       (apply (deref (var ~macro))
              '(~macro ~@args ~@rest-args)
              nil
              ~@(map #(list 'quote %) args)
              '~rest-args))))
```

Usage:

```
hackery> (->> (range 5) rest rest rest rest)
(4)
hackery> (apply-macro ->> (range 5) (repeat 4 'rest))
(4)
```

Qualifications:

1. The macro should not be quoted, and the intervening arguments are passed unevaluated to the macro. However, the "rest" argument **is** evaluated, and must evaluate to a list of symbols or forms, each of which will be passed unevaluated to the macro.
2. This will not work with macros that make use of the [`&env`](http://blog.jayfields.com/2011/02/clojure-and.html) argument.

Answer (score -1):

This approach **doesn't work if the argument list can have unbounded length**, but if you only need to apply to lists up to length `n` you can make a wrapper function with `n` arities:

```
user> (defmacro foo [& rest] `(println ~@rest))
#'user/foo
user> (apply foo [1 2])
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't take value of a macro: #'user/foo, compiling:(*cider-repl repo*:865:7) 
user> (defn foo-up-to-ten-args
  ([a]                   (foo a))
  ([a b]                 (foo a b))
  ([a b c]               (foo a b c))
  ([a b c d]             (foo a b c d))
  ([a b c d e]           (foo a b c d e))
  ([a b c d e f]         (foo a b c d e f))
  ([a b c d e f g]       (foo a b c d e f g))
  ([a b c d e f g h]     (foo a b c d e f g h))
  ([a b c d e f g h i]   (foo a b c d e f g h i))
  ([a b c d e f g h i j] (foo a b c d e f g h i j)))
#'user/foo-up-to-ten-args
user> (apply foo-up-to-ten-args [1 2])
1 2
nil
user> (apply foo-up-to-ten-args (range 0 10))
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
nil
user> (apply foo-up-to-ten-args (range 0 11))
ArityException Wrong number of args (11) passed to: user/foo-up-to-ten-args  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:429)
```

In my case this did what I needed without `eval`.