# How can I apply 'or' in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I have a sequence of values. I want to know if any of them evaluates true.

```
(def input [nil nil nil 1 nil 1])
```

I want to do something like this:

```
(apply or input)
```

But I can't because `or` [is a macro](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L806) not a function. Similarly this won't work

```
(reduce or input)
```

I've written my own

```
(def orfn #(if %1 %1 %2))
```

And now this works

```
(reduce orfn input)
```

As does this slightly different approach, although it only tests for `nil`.

```
(not (every? nil? input))
```

What's the 'right' way to `apply or` or equivalent?

Comment: in general case [this can help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273333/in-clojure-how-to-apply-a-macro-to-a-list)

Comment: Great, thanks @soulcheck. I think that the best solution to the problem I am having is `some`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `some` with `identity` to do this:

```
(some identity [nil nil nil 1 nil 1])
=> 1
```

`some` returns the first truthy value from applying a function to a sequence, so this works because `1` is a truthy value.

Answer (score 4):

`(some identity [nil nil nil nil 1 nil 1])`