# How to pass a list to clojure's `->` macro?

Tags: list, clojure, macros, apply

I'm trying to find a way to thread a value through a list of functions.

Firstly, I had a usual ring-based code:

```
(defn make-handler [routes]
  (-> routes
      (wrap-json-body)
      (wrap-cors)
      ;; and so on
      ))
```

But this was not optimal as I wanted to write a test to check the routes are actually wrapped with wrap-cors. I decided to extract the wrappers into a def. So the code became as follows:

```
(def middleware
  (list ('wrap-json-body)
        ('wrap-cors)
        ;; and so on
        ))

(defn make-handler [routes]
  (-> routes middleware))
```

This apparently doesn't work and is not supposed to as the `->` macro doesn't take a list as the second argument. So I tried to use the `apply` function to resolve that:

```
(defn make-handler [routes]
  (apply -> routes middleware))
```

Which eventually bailed out with:

> CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't take value of a
>   macro: #'clojure.core/->

So the question arises: How does one pass a list of values to the `->` macro (or, say, any other macro) as one would do with `apply` for a function?

Comment: Maybe this is a duplicate and [In clojure, how to apply a macro to a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273333/in-clojure-how-to-apply-a-macro-to-a-list) answers your question.

Comment: @sloth, thanks for pointing that one out. While it provides some ideas on how the problem could be tackled, I like the answer by leetwinsky more, as it's more semantic and clean to my taste.

Comment: The main point of `->` is to make code easier to read. But if you are writing a new macro solely so that you can use `->` (in code you'll never see because it exists only at macro-expansion), I don't see the point. In the spirit of never using a macro where functions will do, I suggest the following solution: `(reduce #(%2 %) routes middleware)`

Comment: @galdre Your comment should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make a macro for that:

```
;; notice that it is better to use a back quote, to qoute function names for macro, as it fully qualifies them.
(def middleware
  `((wrap-json-body)
    (wrap-cors))
    ;; and so on
   )

(defmacro with-middleware [routes]
  `(-> ~routes ~@middleware))
```

for example this:

```
(with-middleware [1 2 3])
```

would expand to this:

```
(-> [1 2 3] (wrap-json-body) (wrap-cors))
```

Answer (score 6):

*This is an XY Problem*.

The main point of `->` is to make code easier to read. But if one writes a new macro solely in order to use `->` (in code nobody will ever see because it exists only at macro-expansion), it seems to me that this is doing a lot of work for no benefit. Moreover, I believe it obscures, rather than clarifies, the code.

So, in the spirit of never using a macro where functions will do, I suggest the following two equivalent solutions:

**Solution 1**

```
(reduce #(%2 %) routes middleware)
```

**Solution 2**

```
((apply comp middleware) routes)
```

**A Better Way**

The second solution is easily simplified by changing the definition of `middleware` from being a list of the functions to being the [composition](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/comp) of the functions:

```
(def middleware
    (comp wrap-json-body
          wrap-cors
          ;; and so on
          ))

(middleware routes)
```

When I began learning Clojure, I ran across this pattern often enough that many of my early projects have an `freduce` defined in core:

```
(defn freduce
   "Given an initial input and a collection of functions (f1,..,fn),
   This is logically equivalent to ((comp fn ... f1) input)."
   [in fs]
   (reduce #(%2 %) in fs))
```

This is totally unnecessary, and some might prefer the direct use of `reduce` as being more clear. However, if you don't like staring at `#(%2 %)` in your application code, adding another utility word to your language is fine.

Comment: @gladre, the composition of the functions won't do. The sole purpose of extracting it all in a list was to test the set of middleware applied. Am I missing something and there's a way to know which functions are composed with `comp`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You can know which fns are composed with `comp` by looking at the arguments passed to `comp`. If you want to inspect the fns programmatically, then keep middleware defined as a list and either use `reduce` (solution 1) or `apply comp` (solution 2). `comp`ed fns throw exceptions as normal, with stack traces. If you want to inject a test into the middle, the list approach won't work anyway. If you look at the source of `->` and `comp`, you will see that they perform the exact same nesting of operations, so for program flow they should be the same.

Comment: If it's that you want to inspect `middleware` programmatically to see what functions it includes, the `(reduce middleware ...)` will do less work than a one-time application of `comp`.